# Cisco WLC: Displaying AP configuration commands

Tags: access-point, cli, cisco-wireless, cisco-wlc

Is there a way to display on a WLC a list of commands used for configuration of a given AP? I believe it's possible on Juniper Trapeze WLCs, wouldn't understand why Cisco would disable such an option.

Background to the question: I'd like to copy the config from my old AP to a new one and doing so by ensuring that in GUI all the fields are clicked in the same fashion as they were on the old AP seems really tedious. Is there really no quicker way to configure an AP?

Comment: When using a WLC, APs can’t be configured independently. If your AP is in autonomous mode, then you can download the configuration.

Comment: Some features of their configuration can and is configured independently, such as for instance the hostname, or channels used by a particular AP, whether we want to enable ssh for it, static IP, etc. 

So I'm basically asking if there is a way to view such configuration akin to the outputs of show running-config on Cisco switches.

Comment: Perhaps we're dealing with a semantic difference.  But the short answer to your original question is No.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

If your question is to get the following AP configs ..

> AP#capwap ap ip address   
>   AP#capwap ap ip default-gateway  
>   AP#capwap ap primary-base   
>   AP#capwap ap secondary-base   
>   AP#capwap ap hostname

You can check the configuration of the AP with `show capwap ip config`, and after joining the WLC, you can check the details with `show capwap client config`.

In general, it is unnecessary because it is used in a DHCP environment.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way to display on a WLC a list of commands used for configuration of a given AP?

For a given AP? No. But you can list all the commands from the running configuration with the following:

```
 show run-config commands
```

Depending on your configuration this can be a very long output, so two pieces of advice.

1. Enable logging of the output in your SSH client.
2. Disable paging of the output (`config paging disable`) or you will be hitting the space bar quite a bit.

You can dig through the full configuration to pull out anything relevant as you need.

> Is there really no quicker way to configure an AP?

You don't give any details about your configuration, but for general deployments you simply use the defaults and set up your global configurations, RF Profiles, and AP groups properly.

Then the process becomes this:

1. Boot the AP and let it land on the controller (may require an AP image upgrade/downgrade).
2. Give the AP a name: `config ap name <new name> <old name, Ethernet MAC or serial>`
3. (Optional) Configure AP location: `config ap location "<location>" <AP name>`
4. If you configure WLCs in the high availability: `config ap [primary|secondary|tertiary]-base <WLC name> <AP name> <WLC IP>`
5. Assign the AP to the AP group: `config ap group-name <AP Group name> <AP name>` and then `Y`.

After a reboot to apply the AP group and RF profile settings, the AP will be in service.

Naturally, if you are doing something outside of the "normal" AP deployment (flex, mesh, etc), then the process becomes a bit more involved, but you should be able to figure what else is needed from the configuration.